# types exists in both Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll and System.Data.Services.Client.dll

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

After upgrading to latest NuGet packages a get a number of errors of the form:

> The type XYZ exists in both Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll and
>   System.Data.Services.Client.dll

All that I can find about this is this [question](http://forums.asp.net/p/1924563/5462111.aspx?DataServiceContext%20exists%20in%20both%20Microsoft%20Data%20Services%20and%20System%20Data%20Services%20assemblies) where the answer refers to 'latest features' and a link that seems to be about the philosophical differences in the namespaces.

Which DLL should I use?

Comment: If all your modules/packages links to System.* and you do not need anything _cool_ from Microsoft.* then I would go with System.*. Very opinion based but I don't like to care about breaking changes in deployed applications and I'm always happy to have less libs to redist.

Comment: @Adriano - Thanks, that is what I have done. Is there anywhere that I would look to find out what the *cool* Microsoft things are (or what the differences are)? Also, could you expand on 'not care about breaking changes' (or shoot me a link that gives some info)?

Comment: For differences I'd just explore namespaces/methods. About breaking changes I mean in future. Microsoft.* is pretty stable but they (may) do not worry too much to make a breaking change..